# Run two separate jQuery simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get two different jquery to run at the same time.

One thing (Design jQuery is how I'll refer to it) is related to a carousel and smooth scrolling, and automatically highlighting the current area in the navbar.

The second is a Konami code script which I would like to implement as an Easter egg.

When I remove the Design jQuery, the konami code works as it should in the browser.
However when it is added to the site, the konami code is unable to work.

Is there some way to getting them to both both at the same time?..

Comment: [jQuery.noConflict](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) would allow you to add 2 different version of jquery to your page. But you shouldn't need to, what are you using for the konami code?

Comment: Well, to be totally honest, I don't know how to use jQuery at all.
the Design jQuery functions are http://pastebin.com/Rfmd9avN and the actual functionality of the konami code comes from something called cheet.js.
I then have a function which references the cheet.js, and runs the konami code function(Appear), which someone online made for me after I asked them to. http://pastebin.com/kFsQNYSD

Answer (score 1):

If you are not doing it already, define the Design jQuery and the Konami code script and run each of those using `$(document).ready(varName);`

Answer (score 1):

You can run two jquery using [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/). If you must refer to jquery as $, you can pass jQuery as a parameter to self invoking function. Example:

var jquery_one = jQuery.noConflict();

```
(function($){
    //code that use jquery as $
})(jquery_one);
```

Comment: Perfect! Does exactly what I need to do.

Comment: Well actually had it working for a second but now it isn't working. Actually causing everything to stop.. Do they both have to be encapsulated in this framework? Just the presence of var jquery_one = jQuery.noConflict(); makes it stop.

Comment: It's now running without this code, on it's own...
Man - Jquery is temperamental... No doubt it will stop working again in 10 minutes..

Comment: run both jquery as noConflict, and than either 1) encapsulate both with respective jquery or 2) encapsulate one (ex. konami) and bring back $ variable to window scope for the other code